# Listing UID Numbers of friends to query database

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

sorry for the noobie question here but I've been struggling for a while. I'm developing an app I'm trying to query my database to add points whenever a friend starts using the app. I've been using this FQL command to find friends using the app

```
SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) AND is_app_user=1
```

This brings the results in an array of just the UIDs of friends already using the app. Like so (All of these are test users):

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [uid] => 100003095627567 ) [1] => Array ( [uid] => 100003256239213 ) [2] => Array ( [uid] => 100003296198341 ) )
```

The problem I'm running into is that I need all of the UID's in a single variable separated by commas like (UID1, UID2, UID3) so I can query the database on my end. I've already tried the ForEach command but thats not working. Any help or a suggested workaround would be nice :)

Comment: You’ve got no single-dimensional array here, but an array containing arrays. So in a foreach loop on the outer array, you will have to access the element of the inner arrays – which is easy, since they are all having just one element with the same key every time. Should be no problem at all, provided one knows the absolute basics of array data structures in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array (
    array ( 'uid' => '100003095627567' ),
    array ( 'uid' => '100003256239213' ),
    array ( 'uid' => '100003296198341' )
);
var_dump($a);

echo '<br/>'.PHP_EOL;

$v = array();          // (*)
foreach ($a as $u) {   // (*)
    $v[] = $u['uid'];  // (*)
}                      // (*)
var_dump($v);

echo '<br/>'.PHP_EOL;

$uids = join(',', $v); // (**)
var_dump($uids);
?>
```

Output:

> array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["uid"]=> string(15) "100003095627567" } [1]=> array(1) { ["uid"]=> string(15) "100003256239213" } [2]=> array(1) { ["uid"]=> string(15) "100003296198341" } }
>
> array(3) { [0]=> string(15) "100003095627567" [1]=> string(15) "100003256239213" [2]=> string(15) "100003296198341" }
>
> string(47) "100003095627567,100003256239213,100003296198341"